# Usefulness of the state_values calculation in Dynamic Programming

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dynamic-programming

State values are always presented as a central concept in RL, notoriously in the bible, the Sutton&Barton’s book.

I have done some exercises trying to improve my understanding, but it is clear that I am missing some important point(s), at least in the tabular case.

I do not understand, in the case where we have a complete MDP model of the environment, why we should bother doing value iteration or/and policy iteration if we can directly find the optimal policy by calculating each state-action value.  I mean that having the state-action values, we can by the argmax function obtain the optimal policy for any starting point.

In my learning/example, [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtRJF8vUAqVCtNRxywOVO2tKrgTPxA?e=11CTFv), with an observation space of one million states and three different actions, using a desktop notebook it took 21 iterations in 19 minutes to find every state action value, and consequently,  the optimal policy.

Perhaps it could be done quicker, selecting only the interesting states. For instance, if there is a unique starting state and the simulation has a finite-small number of steps per episode, probably most of the states are uninteresting because never visited. In that case, we can select the target states using some test simulations, but, is it worth?

Comment: Could you please explain more what you mean by "if we can directly find the optimal policy." What would you intend to do differently to state/value calculations? I'd like to understand if you have some other mechanism in mind, or are more concerned about basic dynamic programming calculating *all* the state values (including ones yuo may not care about). Your last paragraph mentions that point, but the title and first four paragraphs are not, and kind of imply you are looking for an alternative to any kind of value calculation

Comment: ok. I'll edit my question

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am confused though, where do you think the state-action values that you want to use for your policy are coming from? They are not part of the environment model. The dynamic programming is calculating them (or the state values normally, but it can easily calculate action values if that's what you want). But you seem to want to not do that calculation - where will you get the values from instead?

Comment: Ies. As I said, I calculate them, and the state_action_value is solved. What for solving the "state_value"? In some sense, I think I do not understand the interest of the prediction problem. It seems to me that solving the control problem is enough.

Comment: Your question is about not calculating them though, and still using them? How are you calculating the state action values without using a value-based method? How, exactly are you calculating $q^*(s,a)$ *without* using dynamic programming in your case where you want to go straight to the optimal policy?

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "if we can directly find the optimal policy by calculating each state-action value". Are you asking why do we estimate V(s) if we can simply estimate Q(s, a) (from which we can directly derive the policy)?

Comment: @nbro. Ies. This is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @nbro Also, why calculate Q(s,a) following a specific policy instead of calculate it following an exhaustive sweep search ? In the tabular situation, it seems reasonable.

Comment: @HermesMorales Ok, I suggested that you edit your post to clarify your question and leave the question in the form I've written it. After you've edited it, more people should see it.